# SQL: How to filter after aggregation?

Tags: sql, select, aggregation

It is very easy to remove values that you don't want aggregated.

For instance:

```
SELECT department, SUM(sales) as "Total sales"
FROM order_details
GROUP BY department
HAVING SUM(sales) > 1000;
```

Which will exclude all sales with a value less than or equal to 1000 from the summing aggregation.

But how do you filter after the aggregation?

E.g. `WHERE ("Total sales"> 15000)`

Edit: Ironically I was only including `HAVING SUM(sales) > 1000;` in order to prevent confusion about the type of query required; because I'm not actually interested in excluding items from the summing, just the returned results! Thanks, despite confusion!

Comment: can you give sample records? Your problem is simple but you are statement is confusing.

Comment: Not understanding your question. You are already doing what you ask for. You query filter all the departement with an aggregation less than 1000. Can you rephrase?

Comment: To rephrase: a filtering of the returned values. The query will exclude results less than X. Probably more efficient ways to go about it as it seems a bit of a waste to do calculation that will subsequently be excluded.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The query you have is actually doing what you want and not what you expressed in the question. If you want to exclude all sales with a value less than 1000, you should use `WHERE sales > 1000`. But with `HAVING SUM(sales) > 1000` the filtering is actually done after the aggregation.

Writing a sub-query and adding another `SELECT WHERE` on top of the original query is redundant.

Please see [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30c3f/14/0) for clarification.

```
#Query1

SELECT department, SUM(sales) as Total
FROM order_details
GROUP BY department
HAVING Total > 40;

#Query 2

SELECT department, SUM(sales) as Total
FROM order_details
GROUP BY department
HAVING  SUM(sales) > 40;

#Query 3

SELECT department, SUM(sales) as Total
FROM order_details
WHERE sales > 40
GROUP BY department;

#Query 1 and 2 are the same, filtering after aggregation
#Query 3 is filtering before aggregation
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to filter the sale with value less than 1000, the right query is

```
SELECT department, sales
FROM order_details
WHERE sales > 1000
```

If you want to aggregate, and keep only the sum be more than 15000, then you need this query :

```
SELECT department, SUM(sales) as TotalSales
FROM order_details
WHERE sales > 1000
GROUP BY department
HAVING SUM(sales) > 15000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a two-step process by selecting the sum into a temp table, then selecting from the temp table:

```sql
SELECT department, SUM(sales) as TotalSales
INTO #temp
FROM order_details
GROUP BY department
HAVING SUM(sales) > 1000

SELECT department, TotalSales
FROM #temp
WHERE TotalSales > 15000

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: This is exactly an example of what should not be done. Replace 1000 with 15000 in the first query and you get the same result.

Comment: @jurgenreza You are right, of course, that it is a redundant filter.  I was answering his question using his queries though (a bit of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Still, based on his description, he could intend to filter by different fields in his actual query, and this approach would work for that.