# Display one type of result when using case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, case

I'm writing a query to see if a customer has more than 2 computers and I'm using case. How do I display only "multiple" (more than 1 computers) in my result. I don't want to show the single one.

```
select (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT computerID) = 1 THEN 'single' 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT computerID) <> 1 THEN 'multiple' 
        END) AS computerIDs
    , count(distinct computerID) as howmanycomputers
    , pjmpsid
from [data]..clientdata
inner join computer with (nolock) on computerID = dccomputerID
where cliententrytime between '2021-06-11 00:00' and '2021-07-12'
group by clientID
order by clientID asc
```

So right now my query returns all the clients with both single and multiple computerIDs. How do I modify my query so I will only show multiple results only for computerIDs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL: How to filter after aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767794/sql-how-to-filter-after-aggregation)

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`having`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause e.g.

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT computerID) > 1
```

Which comes directly after the `GROUP BY` i.e.

```
...
GROUP BY clientID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT computerID) > 1
ORDER BY clientID asc
```

Comment: Can you write a full query please? THank you.